# In IE codeigniter losing session during ajax

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, internet-explorer, session

In Internet Explorer Codeigniter losing session userdata during AJAX.
In all browser works fine everything, but in IE :( :(

If there isn't AJAX session is in IE too. It loose only AJAX call.

I've googled for solution. I've tried different solutions, but unsuccessfully.

My Settings:

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'cisession';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

AJAX response must be user_id, but in IE is FALSE

Answer (score 0):

change sess_expiration from 7200 to 84200